# Android Studio unit testing support vs robolectric

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, robolectric

Hitherto I used robolectric unit testing with JUnit 4.x for testing my business logic. In the last version of Android Studio 1.1.0 was announced [native support](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) of unit testing `junit:4.+`.

Should I refuse using robolectric? Has robolectric some distinct advantages that I might not know?

As for me using Android Studio native tests more convenient and simpler. In the robolectric test results are stored in html file and can be displayed in the browser(which not convinient for me). Native Android Studio test results are displayed in the Run output window, if some test fails, we can easily open this line of code by clicking on the error in the output window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason you cannot use both. Robolectric has the advantage that you can test against actual Android behaviour when needed. Plain JUnit will just let you test the parts of your code that do not interact with Android.

This will let you view the results of the robolectric tests in Android Studio along with the plain JUnit 4.x tests

If you are using gradle, the [robolectric example github repo](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle) has an example of how to do it.

I'm currently migrating a few apps to use this approach

Here are the relevant parts of the build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1'
    testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }
}
```

The test classes shouldn't need any modification

Comment: com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test is deprecated (https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test/blob/master/README.md). Can someone provide a non-deprecated Robolectric solution that works well with both androidTestCompile, and testCompile? The Android Tools team is currently "TBD" (aka: mum) http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/test-modules#TOC-Android-Test-App-using-Robolectric

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to enable jacoco output for Android's support for Unit Tests? When I "android { buildTypes { debug { testCoverageEnabled = true } }  jacoco { version = '0.7.3.201502191951' } }" I get no jacoco output. If I "apply plugin: 'jacoco'" the testDebug task fails with the output "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_932a715.PreMain". FYI: I am putting together my own SO question to give a bit more detail.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't

Comment: Actually, I do get a jacoco.exec output in my project root. I hadn't noticed that before, because I was expecting it to be in by build directory. Another problem was that I accidentally had written "android { ... buildTypes { ... jacoco { version = '0.7.3.201502191951' } } }" instead of "android { ... buildTypes { ... } jacoco { version = '0.7.3.201502191951' } }". It also appears to no longer be needed and seems to work fine without it.

Comment: I case it isn't clear, you do NOT need "apply plugin: 'jacococ'" in your build.gradle file! You only need to specify "android { buildTypes { debug { testCoverageEnabled true } } }"